# how can i implement plain gradient descent with keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am a student learning deep learning.
These days, I am trying to see the plot of a loss function with respect to weights and bias.
Especially, I want to apply gradient descent method to get smooth lines rather than random characteristics orginated from other optimizers.

Keras framework offers various types of optimizers such as SGD, RMSprop, Adagrad, AdaDelta, Adam, etc.
However, the normal, general and plain gradient descent(without random characteristics) is not seen in the Keras official document.
Are key arguments, clip normal and clip value relevant to plain GD?
For example, if a SGD optimizer with the key args, clipnormal=1, then would it act a plain SGD?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: SGD is the same as GD if you set `batch_size = n_samples`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! Well, but how do you think about momentum and nesterov arguments which user Pradi KL suggests below? Do you agree with it? Or do you have another opinion? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I think setting batch_size = n_samples is not sufficient, u have to set momentum=0, nesterov=False, inspite of this i didnt see it gets stuck in to local optima, which means it will still has a way to respawn so that it breakout and find new optima

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Pradi KL : ) Well, I have a question to ensure my understanding of your idea. First, according to your suggestion, it seems that if an optimizer has a ability to respawn to find a new optima then it is not GD optimizer. Do I get your idea correctly? Or are you saying that keras SGD with the settings, momentum=0, nesterov=False, is a pure GD?

Comment: @Initd it seems not pure GD with some tricks like adaptivelearning rate, if i run GD with BP using numpy i get different results